# How can I enter into download mode on Samsung Galaxy S Duos 2

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2

I tried to put ClockworkMod recovery onto my Samsung GT-7582 and install CyanogenMod but it doesn't enter into download mode when I use <kbd>volume up</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd>. When I try this I see "Factory Mode" but for testing not for resetting the phone. ;(

How can I install CyanogenMod?

Comment: Just to make things clear, on Samsung devices `Vol Up + Home + Power` boots the **Recovery**. `Vol Down + Home + Power` boots the **Bootloader**, also known as **Download Mode** or **Odin Mode**.

Answer (score 1):

[Android ADB Shell Commands](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/help/shell.html) would be one of the solutions.
To get into download mode, please use following command in a Windows or Linux terminal.

```
adb shell reboot download
```

Comment: On which Android device have you tested this solution? I'm asking this because in adb's help, I don't see any argument named *download*.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try again, please :)

Comment: @Joshua There's no such argument in **adb**. The correct syntax is `adb reboot bootloader`, for Samsung devices.

Comment: `adb reboot bootloader` yields "device not found".   Same if I try `adb shell reboot download`.   I'm in su mode.

Answer (score 0):

You've just catched a clone of a GT-S7582 (There's no solution for it)

Comment: Please provide references.